# Get promisse response with fetch()

Tags: react-native, fetch, es6-promise, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to get the json result of my API using `fetch()` to get data and I'm using async/await to wait promisse resolving, but when my function `fetchArticlesList()` returns in `return responseJson` I'm getting the promisse, like this: `Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}` instead the json.
How can I get the json on my `<Flatlist>` component ?

```
<FlatList
    data={(()=> {
            if (this.props.data)
                return this.props.data

            const response = APIRequest.fetchArticlesList()

            return response
        })()
    } 
    renderItem={(article) => (
        ...
    )}
/>
```

The APIRequest:

```
async fetchArticlesList() {
    try {
        const response     = await fetch(`${apiBackoffice}/articles`)
        const responseJson = await response.json();

        return responseJson; //this returns the promisse, instead of the json. I want to get the json
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use async:  <FlatList data={(  async ()=> { .... })() } /> I can get the promisse result, but then my Flatlist doesn't list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`APIRequest.fetchArticlesList()` is `async` function, that's why it is returning a `Promise` object (take a look the document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)). Load the API response into the `state` and when it is loaded pass it to the `FlatList`. Consider the following sample

```
class SomeComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [], isLoading: true }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    APIRequest.fetchArticlesList().then(data => {
      this.setState({
        data,
        isLoading: false
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, data } = this.state;
    if (isLoading) {
      return <ActivityIndicator .../>
    }
    return (
      <FlatList
       data={data}
       ...
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot! I also found a tutorial like your answer, I'll share to others: https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6